# ListCountourPlot and ListDensityPlot don't show any color

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I used below code to show 2 different plots. But the output is out of colors. Could anyone give an answer to the problem?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ro = 1; 
k = 0.0003; 
kk = 0.0003; 
ke = 0.00042;
dr = 0.06; 
dc = 1000 ;  
tr = 10^-25;
xr = 10^-20;
alpha = 10^-14;
c = 1;
equ = x^2 + ke^2 (dc + 3/4 + v^2 * 10^13/(dr  (2 - 30 e ro)) + 
  alpha * 10^13 ro/ke^2 ) x + ke^2 (( dc ke^2  + alpha * 10^13 ro) ( 
    3/4 +  v^2 * 10^13/(dr  (2 - 30 e ro)) ) - 10^42 alpha  ro c (tr + xr v /(dr (2 - 30 e ro))));
sha = Solve[equ == 0, x];
sh1 = Part[sha, 1];
s1 = x /. sh1;
s1i = ComplexExpand@Im@s1

datas1i = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s1i}, {v , 0, 10^-4, 5*10^-6}, {e, 0.01, 1/(15 ro) - 0.05, 0.05}], 1];

p1 = ListContourPlot[datas1i, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Gray]

ListDensityPlot[datas1i, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]},PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalOmega]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context of this calculation, I can only guess as to the reason the two plots did not produce anything.  But I found two things: it did not seem necessary to apply ComplexExpand@Im to the first solution from Solve[], because when I made the Table[] of values of 's1', rather than 's1i', all values of 's1' were real.  Also, the step size for parameter 'e' in the Table[] needs to be made much smaller, I chose 0.002, otherwise only one value for 'e' is used, because 1/(15 ro) - 0.05 is only 0.0166667.  Anyway, take a look I what I got, with those changes.  I have no idea what a correct answer so should look like, so I apologize if this is not helpful to you.  I could not enter the Mathematica code correctly into this form, so I'm providing two image files.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think your answer doesn't work in some cases. forexample please see below link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144882/flatten-makes-1-0-and-listdensityplot-doesnt-work                                                                                    Am I right?

Comment: That link did not work.  Without any idea what this calculation is about or what a "right" answer might look like, there is little more I can do.